# ASP.NET caching in IIS and hostnames

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, caching

I'm running an MVC3 website in ISS. We have a controller which is fetching images from the database. Which image is actually fetched is decided based on the hostname of the request, e.g. http://hostA.site.com/image/23 returns an image different from http://hostB.site.com/image/23 even though both urls refer same application in IIS.

This works fine until caching gets enabled. I used the following code to allow caching both on the server and the client:

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddHours(1));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.Public);
```

This causes IIS to cache the response, which is exactly what we want to see. However IIS doesn't seem to differentiate between different hostnames when caching. When I first fetch http://hostA.site.com/image/23 an subsequent call to http://hostB.site.com/image/23 causes IIS to return the image cached from the previous request. I assume this happens because IIS considers those requests to be the same because the have the same site and the same URI.

Does anyone know a way to make this work, without having to create different applications for each host? I've set the Cacheability for Private for now, but I'd really like to have IIS cache those images.

Comment: The commands you have place here is for the client. If you cache it on code behind then of cource the code did not know what url is served. Can you see and change the server cache if you use it ?

Comment: The caching happens on the server (when I set HttpCacheability.Public), I verified this using wget which doesn't cache locally. Once I set HttpCacheability.Private IIS stops caching. I wouldn't know how to peak into the internal cache of IIS, so I can't tell whats going on there.

Answer (score 0):

The caching happens on the client, not on the server. So IIS isn't the issue here, except if you're using it to serve up the content expiration header.

If both URLs refer to the same application, you will end up adding the same expiration header regardless of the URL. That code will run in both cases unless you're explicitly looking at the calling URL and adjusting the response you send accordingly.

```
var url = Request.Url.Host;
// Determine which host was called.
// Adjust cache to either 0 or 1 hour based on this
```

Comment: The cache setting isn't the issue, it should be the same for each host. The response content however should be different for each Request.Url.Host. I've got that working, however when I set HttpCacheability.Public IIS starts returning the response of previous call to SiteA when a request for SiteB is made, I verified this using wget. The debugger also shows the code isn't hit when a request for SiteB is done right after a request for SiteA. When I set HttpCacheability.Private everything works again, but I actually want IIS to cache (but correctly).